# How to implement Luracast Restler 2.0 in IIS 7.5 with PHP 5+

Tags: php, api

I have PHP 5 running well in IIS 7.5, and I have successfully implemented a PHP api using Restler.php on my shared linux hosting environment.

To improve development time I have decided to bring the pages local to my Windows environment but cannot get the api to work with the Rest functionality in IIS using Restler.php.

I have searched for documentation to assist with the configuration of IIS or even statements that would tell me I need URL Rewriting tools installed but couldn't find anything that could help nor could I get the API to return anything not even "Hello World".

Comment: Using urls that include `index.php` Restler should work out of the box  on IIS. I'm primarily on Mac. Will get it tested on IIS and include the steps in documentation

Comment: I have done the following testing not sure if it is relevant but hope it helps. testing is url: `localhost/virtualdirectory/api`. Commented out all lines in the index.php and onyl did a echo. That showed that PHP is working in VD.

Comment: Echo worked fine, so line by line I un-commented the index.php 

`require_once 'restler.php';
 
$r = new Restler(); 

$r->addAPIClass('Say');

$r->handle();`

On the last line handle(); I got  this error

`PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\Backup\Web\virtualdirectory\api\restler.php on line 2
PHP Strict Standards:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method DefaultResponse::__formatError() should not be called statically in C:\Backup\Web\virtualdirectory\api\restler.php on line 2`

Comment: Downloaded the latest version Luracast-Restler-v2.0.1-22-gc334e7e and used the normal restler.php not the minimal one and now get the error: `PHP Strict Standards:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method DefaultResponse::__formatError() should not be called statically in C:\Backup\Web\virtualdirectory\api\restler.php on line 293` this line reads `array($this->response, '__formatError'), $status_code, $message)`.

Comment: May I know the version of PHP you are using, I guess it might be lower than 5.3. I just now tested the restler examples on IIS 7.5 and PHP 5.3 they render fine with index.php in the URL. I will create the Web.config example for pretty urls later. Restler is written for PHP 5.3 and should be backward compatible till 5.0 using the combat.php file.

Comment: Hi sure I am using PHP Version 5.3.10, I also found an issue related to my error Issue #29 on https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/29. Are they actually related?

Comment: Downloaded the latest version Luracast-Restler-v2-Stable-0-g0823286 and it resolved the above mentioned error but still cannot access /say/hello. Can we compare PHP configurations?

Comment: I can also access `http://localhost/virtualdirectory/api/index.php/say/hello' perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and followups to the question it is clear that

- **Restler 2.1.4** has cleared the errors you have mentioned
- Using full url (that includes index.php) works fine
- URL rewriting does not work

Restler includes .htaccess files for URL rewriting which are written for Apache servers.

For IIS, you need to install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module, and create a `Web.config` file with the rewrite rules.

[This Guide](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference/) can help you in the process

Comment: Is there a more direct tutorial for IIS to be able to not use the full url? I saw on the restler website that Luracast want to integrate it in the next release, but maybe someone already have written some personal notes about it?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully implemented Restler on Unix and Windows.   The only difference for the Windows implementation is that you need to include index.php in the URL.

So for example on Unix you would have:
http://www.something.com/service/controller/method/parm1/parm2

On Windows you would have:
http://www.something.com/service/index.php/controller/method/parm1/parm2

Hope this helps.   No url rewriting or anything else.  It really does work out the box.